# Jquery AutoComplete For each word

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am really struggling with jQuery's autocomplete plugin. I have a large field in my database with multiple words in it, seperated by spaces:

```
Jumerah Lakes Towers
```

I can get the autocomplete to search for a single word. E.g. if I type "J", it gives me the above string "Jumerah Lakes Towers"

However, if I type a second character like "L", it shall show me all words having second words and starts with an L like below:

```
Jumerah Lakes
```

and so on...

In short I want to match first character with first word's start, second character matches with second word's start and son on..

```
 $("#txtrefid").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
});
```

And my *WHERE* condition in my sql query is `LIKE '%$txt%'`

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is not really designed to do your wish.

I would suggest to create **two distinct autocomplete fields**. 
Then, you will need to **chain** the second autocomplete content on the first autocomplete selection.

By this way, the user would be able to perform a quick research without scrolling a long suggestion list as you want.

Comment: Can not do him two textfield..i want to do it in this one text field with button press

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];
$search = str_split($search, 1);
$search = ' % ' . implode('% ', $search)  . '%';

SELECT ... WHERE `lookup` LIKE '$search'
```

Comment: give me this query..SELECT loc_name FROM crm_location WHERE loc_name LIKE ' % j%'null

Comment: Change `$search = $_REQUEST['search'];` to whatever parameter you use to send the typed characters to the script.

Comment: i did like that,it cancatenate null at the end of query

Answer (score 0):

For your Informations, i did it like this

```
$string = 'HL';
$chars = str_split($string); //split the string into separate characters

$regexp = null; //string for the regexpansion

 foreach($chars as $char) //loop trough the characters
  $regexp .= $char . '[a-z0-9]+ ';

  $regexp = '^' . rtrim($regexp, ' ') . '$'; 
  "WHERE field REGEXP '" . $regexp . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];
$search = str_split($search, 1);
$search = '' . implode('|', $search)  . '';

SELECT ... WHERE `lookup` REGEXP '$search'
```